# Ubuntu on dell chomebook 11 crash on install*

Tags: ubuntu, chrome-book, chrubuntu

I recently got a dell chromebook 11. I promptly installed crouton. then croutons had sound errors so I uninstalled it and decided on chrubuntu.  It worked until it a lot crashed as Well. Finally I decided to reinstall crouton again only to get this error
(This crash was received during the end of the croutons install process, it repeats every time the installation occurs)

```
gzip:unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Failed to complete chroot setup
Unmounting /usr/local/chroots/precise
```

this has proceeded to pop up during every attempt of installing croutons.

Comment: When did you get this error? While doing what? What command did you run? Please [edit] your question and clarify.